# CodeIgniter - is there a GUI based library for cropping an image?

Tags: php, codeigniter

CodeIgniter - is there a GUI based library for cropping an image?

I want to select exactly what and where to crop. Ideally I want to be able to go to

mysite.com/manageImage/crop/example-image.jpg

and it would show the interface to crop it, then crop that image.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is fine a good library then add it as a library in your CI structure. Then the `manageimage` controller's `crop` function will take image name as argument and invoke the cropping library to do its magic. Most of what you will need, since it comes with UI will mean that you need to have some integration effort.

Sadly cannot google and list libraries for you, but I hope you got an idea what direction to proceed.

One good lib that comes to mind is [cropzoom](http://www.cropzoom.com.ar/)